# How to draw the following latex figure horizontally in a row?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, diagrams

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}     
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{nth}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]   
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
%\newtheorem{proof}[theorem]{Proof}


%\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
\usepackage{pifont,geometry,txfonts,hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand{\bcomma}{,\allowbreak}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

\def\M{\mathcal{M}}
%\def\bd{\begin{definition}\rm}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
%\theoremstyle{remark}
%\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
  \begin{center}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65,
       thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=black,
         thick,
         inner sep=2pt,
         minimum size=0.2cm,scale=0.65
       }
     ] 


           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=left:\footnotesize{3}]{};
           \node (a2) at (1.5,0)[acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{4}]{}; 
           \node (a3) at (0,1.5) [acteur,label=below left:\footnotesize{2}]{}; 
           \node (a4) at (-1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below:\footnotesize{1}]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below right:\footnotesize{5}]{}; 
           \node (a6) at (3,1.5) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{6}]{};
           \node (a7) at (0.75,3) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{7}]{}; 
           \node (a8) at (0.75,4.3) [acteur,label=\footnotesize{8}]{}; 

           \draw  (a1) -- (a2); 
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a5); 
           \draw(a5) -- (a6);
           \draw [dashed] (a5) -- (a7);
           \draw (a7) -- (a8);
           \draw [dashed] (a7) -- (a3);
           \draw (a3) -- (a4);
           \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a3);

           \draw (0.75, -.9) node {$U_{1}$};
         \end{tikzpicture} 
\hspace{2.5cm}
%\textit{$U^{+}$}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65,
       thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=black,
         thick,
         inner sep=2pt,
         minimum size=0.2cm,scale=0.65
       }
     ] 


           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=left:\footnotesize{4}]{};
           \node (a2) at (1.5,0)[acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{3}]{}; 
           \node (a3) at (0,1.5) [acteur,label=below left:\footnotesize{1}]{}; 
           \node (a4) at (-1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below:\footnotesize{2}]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below right:\footnotesize{6}]{}; 
           \node (a6) at (3,1.5) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{5}]{};
           \node (a7) at (0.75,3) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{8}]{}; 
           \node (a8) at (0.75,4.3) [acteur,label=\footnotesize{7}]{}; 

           \draw (a4) -- (a3); 
           \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a3); 
           \draw (a8) -- (a7);
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a5);
           \draw (a6) -- (a5);
           \draw [dashed] (a3) -- (a7);
           \draw (a1) -- (a2);
           \draw [dashed] (a5) -- (a7);
           \draw [dashed] (a3) -- (a5);

           \draw (0.95, -1) node {$U_{1}^{+}$};

         \end{tikzpicture} 

   \vspace{.2cm}     


        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65,
       thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=black,
         thick,
         inner sep=2pt,
         minimum size=0.2cm,scale=0.65
       }
     ] 



           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=left:\small{1}]{};
           \node (a2) at (1.5,0)[acteur,label=below:\small{2}]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (3,0) [acteur,label=below:\small{5}]{}; 
           \node (a6) at (4.5,0) [acteur,label=right:\small{6}]{}; 
           \node (a3) at (2.25,1.5) [acteur,label=right:\small{3}]{}; 
           \node (a4) at (2.25,3) [acteur,label=right:\small{4}]{};

           \draw  (a1) -- (a2); 
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a5); 
           \draw(a5) -- (a6);
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a3);

           \draw [dashed] (a3) -- (a5);
           \draw (a3) -- (a4);


\node at (2.25,-1.5) {\textit{$U_2$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{2cm}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65,
       thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=black,
         thick,
         inner sep=2pt,
         minimum size=0.2cm,scale=0.65
       }
     ] 


           \node (a3) at (0,0) [acteur,label=left:\footnotesize{3}]{};
           \node (a4) at (1.5,0)[acteur,label=below:\footnotesize{4}]{}; 
           \node (a6) at (3,0) [acteur,label=below:\footnotesize{6}]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (4.5,0) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{5}]{}; 
           \node (a1) at (2.25,1.5) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{1}]{}; 
           \node (a2) at (2.25,3) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{2}]{};

           \draw  (a3) -- (a4); 
           \draw [dashed] (a4) -- (a6); 
           \draw(a5) -- (a6);
           \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a4);

           \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a6);
           \draw (a2) -- (a1);




\node at (2.25,-1.5) {\textit{$U_{2}^{+}$}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\vspace{-9mm}
\caption{Here the solid edges are the matching edges.}\label{h2}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to draw these figures in a single horizontal line. How can we do this?

Comment: Rrmoving the `\vspace` and the blank lines between the `tikzpicture`s and reducing the horizontal space between them should do it. You may also need to reduce the `scale=` factor to get it to fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below

1. Removes the blank lines and the `\vspace` between the `tikzpicutre` enivonments.
2. Replaces the horizontal separation between adjacent `tikzpicutre` with an `\hfill` and
3. Redcudes the size of the figures by adjust the `scale=` parameter.
4. Eliminate the uneeded pacakges for the curent issue.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}    

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50,
       thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=black,
         thick,
         inner sep=2pt,
         minimum size=0.2cm,scale=0.65,
       }
     ] 


           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=left:\footnotesize{3}]{};
           \node (a2) at (1.5,0)[acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{4}]{}; 
           \node (a3) at (0,1.5) [acteur,label=below left:\footnotesize{2}]{}; 
           \node (a4) at (-1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below:\footnotesize{1}]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below right:\footnotesize{5}]{}; 
           \node (a6) at (3,1.5) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{6}]{};
           \node (a7) at (0.75,3) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{7}]{}; 
           \node (a8) at (0.75,4.3) [acteur,label=\footnotesize{8}]{}; 

           \draw  (a1) -- (a2); 
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a5); 
           \draw(a5) -- (a6);
           \draw [dashed] (a5) -- (a7);
           \draw (a7) -- (a8);
           \draw [dashed] (a7) -- (a3);
           \draw (a3) -- (a4);
           \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a3);

           \draw (0.75, -.9) node {$U_{1}$};
         \end{tikzpicture}% 
  \hfill
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50,
       thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=black,
         thick,
         inner sep=2pt,
         minimum size=0.2cm,scale=0.65
       }
     ] 


           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=left:\footnotesize{4}]{};
           \node (a2) at (1.5,0)[acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{3}]{}; 
           \node (a3) at (0,1.5) [acteur,label=below left:\footnotesize{1}]{}; 
           \node (a4) at (-1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below:\footnotesize{2}]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below right:\footnotesize{6}]{}; 
           \node (a6) at (3,1.5) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{5}]{};
           \node (a7) at (0.75,3) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{8}]{}; 
           \node (a8) at (0.75,4.3) [acteur,label=\footnotesize{7}]{}; 

           \draw (a4) -- (a3); 
           \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a3); 
           \draw (a8) -- (a7);
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a5);
           \draw (a6) -- (a5);
           \draw [dashed] (a3) -- (a7);
           \draw (a1) -- (a2);
           \draw [dashed] (a5) -- (a7);
           \draw [dashed] (a3) -- (a5);

           \draw (0.95, -1) node {$U_{1}^{+}$};

         \end{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50,
       thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=black,
         thick,
         inner sep=2pt,
         minimum size=0.2cm,scale=0.65
       }
     ] 

           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=left:\small{1}]{};
           \node (a2) at (1.5,0)[acteur,label=below:\small{2}]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (3,0) [acteur,label=below:\small{5}]{}; 
           \node (a6) at (4.5,0) [acteur,label=right:\small{6}]{}; 
           \node (a3) at (2.25,1.5) [acteur,label=right:\small{3}]{}; 
           \node (a4) at (2.25,3) [acteur,label=right:\small{4}]{};

           \draw  (a1) -- (a2); 
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a5); 
           \draw(a5) -- (a6);
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a3);

           \draw [dashed] (a3) -- (a5);
           \draw (a3) -- (a4);


\node at (2.25,-1.5) {\textit{$U_2$}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hfill
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,
       thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=black,
         thick,
         inner sep=2pt,
         minimum size=0.2cm,
         scale=0.65
       }
     ] 
           \node (a3) at (0,0) [acteur,label=left:\footnotesize{3}]{};
           \node (a4) at (1.5,0)[acteur,label=below:\footnotesize{4}]{}; 
           \node (a6) at (3,0) [acteur,label=below:\footnotesize{6}]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (4.5,0) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{5}]{}; 
           \node (a1) at (2.25,1.5) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{1}]{}; 
           \node (a2) at (2.25,3) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{2}]{};

           \draw  (a3) -- (a4); 
           \draw [dashed] (a4) -- (a6); 
           \draw(a5) -- (a6);
           \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a4);

           \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a6);
           \draw (a2) -- (a1);

\node at (2.25,-1.5) {\textit{$U_{2}^{+}$}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{center}
\vspace{-9mm}
\caption{Here the solid edges are the matching edges.}\label{h2}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As off-topic supplement to @Peter Grill answer (+1):

- common style for nodes in images
- common style for labels
- connection lines are grouped to command with solid lines and fr dashed lines.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \tikzset{
       thick,
       acteur/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm},
       every label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize,inner sep=2pt},
            }

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
    \node (a1) at (0,0)     [acteur,label=left:3]{};
    \node (a2) at (1.5,0)   [acteur,label=right:4]{};
    \node (a3) at (0,1.5)   [acteur,label=below left:2]{};
    \node (a4) at (-1.5,1.5)[acteur,label=below:1]{};
    \node (a5) at (1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below right:5]{};
    \node (a6) at (3,1.5)   [acteur,label=below:6]{};
    \node (a7) at (0.75,3)  [acteur,label=right:7]{};
    \node (a8) at (0.75,4.3)[acteur,label=8]{};
%
    \draw   (a1) -- (a2)    (a5) -- (a6)    (a7) -- (a8)    (a3) -- (a4);
    \draw [dashed]  (a2) -- (a5)    (a5) -- (a7)    (a7) -- (a3) 
                    (a1) -- (a3);
    \node at (0.75, -.9) {$U_{1}$};
         \end{tikzpicture}
\hfil
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
    \node (a1) at (0,0)     [acteur,label=left:4]{};
    \node (a2) at (1.5,0)   [acteur,label=right:3]{};
    \node (a3) at (0,1.5)   [acteur,label=below left:1]{};
    \node (a4) at (-1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below:2]{};
    \node (a5) at (1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below right:6]{};
    \node (a6) at (3,1.5)   [acteur,label=below:5]{};
    \node (a7) at (0.75,3)  [acteur,label=right:8]{};
    \node (a8) at (0.75,4.3)[acteur,label=7]{};
%
    \draw   (a1) -- (a2)    (a5) -- (a6)    (a7) -- (a8)    (a3) -- (a4);
    \draw [dashed]  (a2) -- (a5)    (a5) -- (a7)    (a7) -- (a3)
                    (a1) -- (a3);
    \node at (0.95, -.9) {$U_{1}^{+}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfil
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
           \node (a3) at (0,0)  [acteur,label=left:1]{};
           \node (a4) at (1.5,0)[acteur,label=below:2]{};
           \node (a6) at (3,0)  [acteur,label=below:5]{};
           \node (a5) at (4.5,0)[acteur,label=below:6]{};
           \node (a1) at (2.25,1.5) [acteur,label=right:3]{};
           \node (a2) at (2.25,3)[acteur,label=right:4]{};
%
    \draw   (a3) -- (a4)    (a5) -- (a6)    (a2) -- (a1);
    \draw [dashed]  (a4) -- (a6)    (a1) -- (a4) (a1) -- (a6);
\node at (2.25,-1.5) {\textit{$U_2$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfil
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
    \node (a3) at (0,0)     [acteur,label=left:3]{};
    \node (a4) at (1.5,0)   [acteur,label=below:4]{};
    \node (a6) at (3,0)     [acteur,label=below:6]{};
    \node (a5) at (4.5,0)   [acteur,label=below:5]{};
    \node (a1) at (2.25,1.5)[acteur,label=right:1]{};
    \node (a2) at (2.25,3)  [acteur,label=right:2]{};
%
    \draw   (a3) -- (a4)    (a5) -- (a6)    (a2) -- (a1);
    \draw [dashed]  (a4) -- (a6)    (a1) -- (a4) (a1) -- (a6);
\node at (2.25,-1.5) {\textit{$U_{2}^{+}$}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Here the solid edges are the matching edges.}
\label{h2}

    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Answer (score 2):

Just place all the figures in the same `tikzpicture` environment and shift them with a `scope` environment.
I commented the parts of your code that are no longer needed.
It is possible to align the figures so that the triangles are aligned.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}     
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{nth}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]   
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
%\newtheorem{proof}[theorem]{Proof}


%\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
\usepackage{pifont,geometry,txfonts,hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand{\bcomma}{,\allowbreak}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

\def\M{\mathcal{M}}
%\def\bd{\begin{definition}\rm}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
%\theoremstyle{remark}
%\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
  \begin{center}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,
       thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=black,
         thick,
         inner sep=2pt,
         minimum size=0.2cm,scale=0.65
       }
     ] 


           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=left:\footnotesize{3}]{};
           \node (a2) at (1.5,0)[acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{4}]{}; 
           \node (a3) at (0,1.5) [acteur,label=below left:\footnotesize{2}]{}; 
           \node (a4) at (-1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below:\footnotesize{1}]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below right:\footnotesize{5}]{}; 
           \node (a6) at (3,1.5) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{6}]{};
           \node (a7) at (0.75,3) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{7}]{}; 
           \node (a8) at (0.75,4.3) [acteur,label=\footnotesize{8}]{}; 

           \draw  (a1) -- (a2); 
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a5); 
           \draw(a5) -- (a6);
           \draw [dashed] (a5) -- (a7);
           \draw (a7) -- (a8);
           \draw [dashed] (a7) -- (a3);
           \draw (a3) -- (a4);
           \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a3);

           \draw (0.75, -.9) node {$U_{1}$};
%         \end{tikzpicture} 
%\hspace{2.5cm}
%%\textit{$U^{+}$}
%  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
%[scale=0.65,
%       thick,
%       acteur/.style={
%         circle,
%         fill=black,
%         thick,
%         inner sep=2pt,
%         minimum size=0.2cm,scale=0.65
%       }
%     ] 


           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=left:\footnotesize{4}]{};
           \node (a2) at (1.5,0)[acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{3}]{}; 
           \node (a3) at (0,1.5) [acteur,label=below left:\footnotesize{1}]{}; 
           \node (a4) at (-1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below:\footnotesize{2}]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below right:\footnotesize{6}]{}; 
           \node (a6) at (3,1.5) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{5}]{};
           \node (a7) at (0.75,3) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{8}]{}; 
           \node (a8) at (0.75,4.3) [acteur,label=\footnotesize{7}]{}; 

           \draw (a4) -- (a3); 
           \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a3); 
           \draw (a8) -- (a7);
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a5);
           \draw (a6) -- (a5);
           \draw [dashed] (a3) -- (a7);
           \draw (a1) -- (a2);
           \draw [dashed] (a5) -- (a7);
           \draw [dashed] (a3) -- (a5);

           \draw (0.95, -1) node {$U_{1}^{+}$};
\end{scope}

%         \end{tikzpicture} 
%
%   \vspace{.2cm}     
%
%
%        \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
%[scale=0.65,
%       thick,
%       acteur/.style={
%         circle,
%         fill=black,
%         thick,
%         inner sep=2pt,
%         minimum size=0.2cm,scale=0.65
%       }
%     ] 



           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=left:\small{1}]{};
           \node (a2) at (1.5,0)[acteur,label=below:\small{2}]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (3,0) [acteur,label=below:\small{5}]{}; 
           \node (a6) at (4.5,0) [acteur,label=right:\small{6}]{}; 
           \node (a3) at (2.25,1.5) [acteur,label=right:\small{3}]{}; 
           \node (a4) at (2.25,3) [acteur,label=right:\small{4}]{};

           \draw  (a1) -- (a2); 
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a5); 
           \draw(a5) -- (a6);
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a3);

           \draw [dashed] (a3) -- (a5);
           \draw (a3) -- (a4);


\node at (2.25,-1.5) {\textit{$U_2$}};

\end{scope}        
%\end{tikzpicture}
%\hspace{2cm}
% \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=16cm]
%[scale=0.65,
%       thick,
%       acteur/.style={
%         circle,
%         fill=black,
%         thick,
%         inner sep=2pt,
%         minimum size=0.2cm,scale=0.65
%       }
%     ] 


           \node (a3) at (0,0) [acteur,label=left:\footnotesize{3}]{};
           \node (a4) at (1.5,0)[acteur,label=below:\footnotesize{4}]{}; 
           \node (a6) at (3,0) [acteur,label=below:\footnotesize{6}]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (4.5,0) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{5}]{}; 
           \node (a1) at (2.25,1.5) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{1}]{}; 
           \node (a2) at (2.25,3) [acteur,label=right:\footnotesize{2}]{};

           \draw  (a3) -- (a4); 
           \draw [dashed] (a4) -- (a6); 
           \draw(a5) -- (a6);
           \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a4);

           \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a6);
           \draw (a2) -- (a1);




\node at (2.25,-1.5) {\textit{$U_{2}^{+}$}};
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\vspace{-9mm}
\caption{Here the solid edges are the matching edges.}\label{h2}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```